Doctrine truncates PHP \DateTime mili/micro-seconds to 000000
I'm using PHP 8.2, Postgres, Symfony and Doctrine. I try to store a \DateTime property with mili/micro-seconds.
I have defined my entity property as:
...
#[ORM\Column(
    name: 'created_at',
    type: 'datetimetz',
    nullable: true,
    updatable: false,
    columnDefinition: "TIMESTAMPTZ(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",
    options: ['precision' => 6]
)]
private \DateTime $createdAt;
...

After running the migrations the column definition for the created_at column looks like this:
created_at timestamp(6) with time zone default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null
While running my script I can see the createAt property being set to:
^ DateTime @1726928108 {#1378
  date: 2024-09-21 16:15:08.502635 Europe/Amsterdam (+02:00)
}

After persisting the given entity I look at the value of the created_at column for the given record, and it looks like:
2024-09-21 16:15:08.000000 +02:00
After manually editing the created_at column value to: 2024-09-21 16:15:08.000001 +02:00 it shows the mili/micro-/seconds just fine.
So my conclusion is: the column definition for created_at is set up correctly, as the example shows it CAN handle mili/micro-seconds. So I suspect doctrine mishandling my \DateTime values.
How can I fix this issue and let doctrine persist \DateTime values with mili/micro-seconds?
